# Apache ignoring Server Alias and going to first virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, serveralias

I'm having problems getting my ServerAlias domains to work correctly.  apache2ctl -S gives:

```
IP.ADDRESS:80      is a NameVirtualHost
default server byteinsight.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost byteinsight.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
    wild alias *.byteinsight.uk
    wild alias *.byteinsight.co.uk
    wild alias *.bristolwebsitedesigner.co.uk
port 80 namevhost davies-barnard.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:15)
    wild alias *.davies-barnard.uk
port 80 namevhost tdaviesbarnard.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:30)
    wild alias *.greenotter.co.uk
port 80 namevhost weather.davies-barnard.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:57)
port 80 namevhost weewx.davies-barnard.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:70)
port 80 namevhost compu2learn.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:84)
    wild alias *.compu2learn.co.uk
    wild alias *.compu2learn.org.uk
```

I've followed the guidance [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/586550/apache-centos-6-5-only-loading-first-virtual-host) and added the ServerName into the virtual host declaration e.g.

```
<VirtualHost byteinsight.net:80>...
```

and I have restarted Apache.  I tried to add NameVirtualHost *:80 but was told it was not necessary and was going to be removed at the next update.  I have also looked at [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/288284/why-might-apache-ignore-a-virtual-host-with-a-servername-matching-the-requested) and updated my settings to reflect the example given [on the apache TroubleshootingVhosts page](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TroubleshootingVhosts).

What have I missed?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I sussed this out in the end.

First I needed to heed the advice from [VirtualHost ignores ServerName and ServerAlias](https://serverfault.com/questions/463877/virtualhost-ignores-servername-and-serveralias) and put the domain as listed in my main apache.conf file as global ServerName first in the virtual hosts file.

> Main host goes away
>
> If you are adding virtual hosts to an existing web server, you must
>   also create a block for the existing host. The ServerName and
>   DocumentRoot included in this virtual host should be the same as the
>   global ServerName and DocumentRoot. List this virtual host first in
>   the configuration file so that it will act as the default host.

I also need to use full domains and not wild cards e.g.

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com
```

and not

```
ServerAlias *.domain.com.
```